# Multikey sparse index on empty array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

What behavior is expected in this case? Will mongo treat empty array as null/undefined and include it into sparse index or if array is empty, document won't be indexed?

Answer (score 1):

Empty arrays are not treated the same as `null` in MongoDB. As you can see in the following code from the Mongo shell, a sparse index finds the empty array as an empty array as opposed to as `null`.

```
> c = db.docs
test.docs
> c.insert({a : []})
> c.ensureIndex({a : 1}, {sparse: true})
> c.find({a : []}).count()
1
> c.find({a : null}).count()
0
```

As with most interesting questions about MongoDB, using `explain` will provide a wealth of info. For example, you can see that the test actually uses the index and that the boundaries of the index are `null` and `[]`, demonstrating their unique treatment.

```
> c.find({a : null}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 0,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "a" : [
            [
                null,
                null
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "new-host.home:27017"
}
> c.find({a : []}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1 multi",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "a" : [
            [
                null,
                null
            ],
            [
                [ ],
                [ ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "new-host.home:27017"
}
```